# Permit a property if other property is present in Vue Typescript SFC

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-sfc

I want to permit a property (e.g. `modelValue`) of an interface if a other property (e.g. `valueUrl`) is present. Is this possible in TypeScript?

Following Example:

I have a `MyInput.vue` file where you can pass a `modelValue` or a `valueUrl`. It should not be possible to pass both `modelValue` and `valueUrl`.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps<{
    label: string, 
    min?: number,
    max?: number,
    modelValue?: number, 
    valueUrl?: string,
  }>();

  const remoteValue = ref(null);
  if(props.valueUrl){
    // fetch the value from remote service
    remoteValue.value = 99;
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <input :value="modelValue ?? remoteValue">
  </div>
</template>
```

so for example in the last row an error should occur:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import MyInput from './MyInput.vue';

const val = ref(1);
</script>

<template>
  <MyInput label="Valid input via value" v-model="val" />
  <MyInput label="Via input via value url" value-url="https://myUrl.com/myValue"/>
  <MyInput label="This should not be possible" v-model="val" value-url="https://myUrl.com/myValue"/>
</template>
```

You can try this code [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). I'm building a Vue-Component-Library so it would be nice if such an error occurs while compiling and not in runtime.

Comment: This is the case for composite types, `{ ... } & ({ modelValue: number } | { valueUrl: string })`. I expect it to not be properly supported by defineProps, you may need custom prop validator